# SQL Server 2000 Replication not permission issue, what else?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, replication

I am having a challenge with replication on SQL Server 2000, The Replication has full permission,but still given this below error. The SQL Server 2000 is installed in C Drive, but the databse is in E Drive. Thanks for your support

The schema script

> \myserver\Replication\unc\myserver_GS_ECC25_2675_Publication1\20130813090100\SpInsertSbraConf_1469.sch'
>   could not be propagated to the subscriber. (Source: Merge Replication
>   Provider (Agent); Error number: -2147201001)
>
> Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match
>   table definition. (Source: myserver (Data source); Error number: 213)

Comment: What does the table definition of the replicated table(s) look like on the publisher/subscriber - are the definitions the same?  Has anything changed since this was setup?  Is a primary key defined on both?

Comment: Thanks John. Definitions are the same. The primary keys are the same on both tables. It is the same database, but the reason for merge replication, is that the machine is mobile sometimes and so for easy access to the data, replication is needed. Each database has about 206 tables and 500 procedures.

Comment: Sadly no idea I'm afraid. Suggestions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd581610.aspx.  Or try asking on http://dba.stackexchange.com instead; those guys are more clued up around this sort of thing.

Comment: But do you think unc could be turned off. How can I do that in win server 2003.

Comment: No idea I'm afraid - this forum's more for programming questions - if you ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com you'll get help from people who are experts at this stuff.